# My.user.IsInRole always returning false

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration, isinrole

Currently, I'm working in one migration request, where we need to change the framework from 3.5 to 4.6.2. Here the problem is after changing the framework below method is not showing result as expected. `My.User.IsInRole()` is always returning false.

```
If My.User.IsInRole(nlRole.InnerText) Then
   hasRole = True
   Exit For
End If
```

Also, I tested with below code:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

Class PrincipalCheck
    Shared Function UserInRole(role As String) As Boolean
        Dim currPrincipal As New WindowsPrincipal(New WindowsIdentity(Environment.UserName))
        Return currPrincipal.IsInRole(role)
    End Function
End Class

Public Sub StartCheck()
   MsgBox(PrincipalCheck.UserInRole("MyDomain\MyGroup"))
End Sub
```

But no luck. 
Can someone please help me with the above issue.

If you expect some more input from my end, please let me know.

Comment: why does it say "vb6-migration" if its 3.5 to 4.6.2?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, however, check the CaSe of the role, this may be causing inaccurate comparison! - Just an idea :)

Comment: The above mentioned code is also returning false......

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that the problem may be related to the use of `Environment.UserName`. Try replacing that with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, thus:

```
Shared Function UserInRole(role As String) As Boolean
    Dim currPrincipal As New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    Return currPrincipal.IsInRole(role)
End Function
```

However, it is worth remembering that User Account Control can get in the way. If you aren't running elevated then the above won't work for the `WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator`, possibly others. So that might be an issue as well. So worth seeing if you get different results when you run elevated.